# Python, Slicing a string at intervals while keeping the spaces?

Tags: python, string, variables, slice

I need to select every third letter out of a sentence (starting from the first letter), and print out those letters with spaces in between them.

So it should look like this

```
Message? cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
c h a l l e n g e
```

or

```
Message? pbaynatnahproarnsm
p y t h o n
```

I've tried this:

```
nim = input("Line: ")[::+3]
```

and it works fine, but I have to keep the spaces between the letters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.join`:

```
nim = '  '.join(input("Line: ")[::3])
# Line: pbaynatnahproarnsm
print(nim)
```

Output:

```
'p  y  t  h  o  n'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the letters out of sentence with spaces between them, you can use `sep=` parameter of `print()` and asterisk `*`:

```
print(*input("Line: ")[::3], sep=' ')
```

Prints:

```
Line: cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
c h a l l e n g e
```